# Getting FXAA to work

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl, antialiasing, xna-3.0

I am new to HLSL and in all of the tutorials I found there always seems to be a `#include "Fxaa3_11.fxh"` in each of them. I include this file and then it also makes a reference to another header file `#include "Fxaa3_11.h"` and as it goes I also include this file into my content pipeline and still gives me an `error X1507: failed to open source file:...` whichever way I go.

Is there any way to make a clean, single FXAA.fx file without enabling all this mess of external files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile your shader on the fly , you can use this [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.effect.compileeffectfromsource%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

Most important part when using includes is to provide a [CompilerIncludeHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.CompilerIncludeHandler%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) ,include resolves are not automatically done for you (which is a good thing).

You override the open method, then read the include path from the parameters and return the content as a string.

If you just want to have if processed in content manager, Easiest way is probably just to copy paste the content of those header files in the main shader file (where the include is), and delete the include statement. Bit ugly but pretty simple.